# Offset function with in Vlookup for a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Can any one give idea on bellow formula.. Why it is not working

with this formula.. i am trying to get a cell value from a range which is not fixed .. but it starts from B564 cell to till end.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Vlookup(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & "," &"OFFSET($B$564,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)-1)" & ",2,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. How is this not working?

Comment: It showing application or object defined error.

Comment: Your offset returns a one column range, but your Vlookup refers to the second column.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to return a dynamic range from offset.. so that vloopup will look for that range

Comment: It might be enough to use `ActiveCell.Formula = "=Vlookup(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address & "," &"OFFSET($B$564,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)-1,2)" & ",2,FALSE)"`

Comment: Perfect... Its Working .. Thanks a lot for this...!!!!